# LINQ Query using Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, linq

Still trying to get my head around the list and navigation concept rather than basic SQL join language. I have a slightly complex query that requires a fair amount of joins, though the bulk of information are navigable tables (Or have been in the past).

To explain the tables and directions of the queries.

At the top level there is a table called `Company` with a one-to-many relationship with `Areas`.

`Areas` has a many-to-one relationship with a table called `Shifts`.

Another table called `Events` stores a `ShiftID` and it was my thinking once the link between `Event` and `Shift` was made I could then navigate up the chain of relationships.

There are some other tables begin joined in which makes a pure lambda queries (At my current level of understanding) difficult.

---

My code thus far is

```
             var UserEvents = from e in _context.Events
                         join s in _context.Shifts on e.ShiftID equals s.SHFID
                         where e.UID == userID
                         select new UserEvents
                         {
                             EVTID = e.EVTID,
                             UID = e.UID,
                             ShiftID = e.ShiftID,
                             EVTDate = e.EVTDate,
                             Notes = e.Notes,
                             AreaID = s.Area.AreaID,
                             AreaDesc = s.Area.AreaDesc,
                             CPYDesc = s.Area.Company.CPYDesc,
                             StartTime = s.StartTime,
                             EndTime = s.EndTime,
                             RequiredResources = s.RequiredResources,
                             ShiftDesc = s.ShiftDesc,
                             ShiftDayOfWeek = s.ShiftDayOfWeek
                         };
```

The Error that is being given is that Shifts does not contain a definition for Areas. Which in code talk is true, the Shifts.cs does not have a declared field for Area. Though Area has a `public List<Shift> SHFID { get; set; }`

This Query works fine in LINQ PAD but not in VS

Any help or clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if we knew what the `UserEvents` model is, otherwise how can we tell what you're trying to return?  Also, the SQL bears little relation to the LINQ you've shown - are you trying to replicate that SQL in LINQ? Finally, have you seen [LINQpad?](https://www.linqpad.net/) I find it very useful for debugging LINQ queries.

Comment: This LINQ pad is great. I seem to have been going the wrong direction with my query starting from company and going down rather than from shift and join up the tree.   from s in Shifts
where s.SHFID == 1
select new
{
 s.StartTime,
 s.EndTime,
 s.Area,
 s.Area.Company
}